# ILogger<T>.LogMetric of Azure function is not logging messages into Application Insight

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, ilogger

I am using Azure function v3 on .net core 3.x where `ILogger<T>` is created through dependency injection of respective class T through `IServiceProvider like ILogger<T> _log = _log = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<T>>();`

Other than `_log.LogMetric()` every other log messages(traces, information, error, exception etc) are getting pushed to Application Insight. I have checked traces section of transaction search as well as traces and custom metrics of logs.

Even host.json file logging configuration seems to be correct. So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where in Application Insigths are you looking to find those metrics? (Just to make sure you are looking at the right place)

Comment: @PeterBons In Transaction Search section(mainly traces). But search the logs of traces and custom metrics as well.

Comment: Can you post your host.json content and possible some code of the function calling the logmetrics?

Comment: I have identical issue have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a post about this on Github that suggests this is a bug. There is a workaround to inject the `TelemetryClient` and use `client.TrackMetric();`

You can do this:
`services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>(x => new TelemetryClient(configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey").Get<string>()))`

The Configuration here, being your `IConfiguration` or `IConfigurationRoot`

Then after injecting into your service, just call the method, `client.TrackMetric(metricName, metricValue, dictionaryProperties);`

Post in question: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2308

Just a note about this, is that if you're using the TelemetryClient, you'll want to aggregate these metrics yourself with this workaround:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackmetric?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score -3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#log-filtering

From the doc, you will find that only Information, Warning, Debug, Error and Trace will be push to Application Insight.

These five log level doesn't contains LogMetric.

Comment: LogMetric is not a log level, but an extension method that sends data using the Information Log Level ([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/93834ece3dec6f80fe23a9533bbde3bee49ea22f/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Loggers/Logger/LoggerExtensions.cs#L33)). So this answer is not correct/relevant given the current content